# Is it possible to limit resources to a game? Or forcibly limit the FPS

Tags: macbook-pro, video, performance, games

I recently bought and installed a new game through steam 'besiege' if you were wondering, and it ran really hot on my computer. On other games such as CS:GO for example you can cap the FPS in game making my computer not run as hot so less background noise.

I looked around and for this game there doesn't seem to be this option. (I've had similar problems with other games) My Mac (13" macbook pro retina 2013) runs at about 90 - 105 degrees with this game and I know the laptop won't be damaged as it'll thermal throttle and turn up the fans but I'd rather have a worse running game and not so much background noise due to the fan running at 6000 rpm...

My first thought was limiting the resources the game got, I'm not sure if this would affect the heat produced.

But anyways to just make the game run worse to decrease heat output. (It's capped at 60 fps I believe) down to around 20(ish) as this is perfectly bearable visually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the two things you suggested, as these are two separate approaches to solving the issue.

1. Limit the resources provided (presumably by limiting the CPU.)
2. Cap the framerate

Limiting the resources provided is pretty easy (provided you're willing to work with a little bit of third-party software.) You can use [`cputhrottle`](http://www.willnolan.com/cputhrottle/cputhrottle.html) to limit the usage at the system level (better explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24998/can-i-manually-limit-the-cpu-used-by-a-process).)

Capping the framerate is generally done at the level of the game. Unfortunately, [to my knowledge, there's no way to set your framerate cap either lower or higher right now](https://steamcommunity.com/app/346010/discussions/0/612823460271340153/).  So you're stuck with throttling the CPU, although given what you're trying to do, that seems like a fine option.

Comment: I have not really gotten anywhere with cputhrottle (or [AppPolice](https://github.com/fuyu/AppPolice)) with the couple of games I tried it with. CPU usage is limited, but the framerate becomes choppy and fan noise is not significantly reduced.

Comment: @BrechtMachiels Probably because something else (likely the GPU) isn't being throttled. If possible, I'd suggest capping the framerate instead. What games are you playing?

Comment: Rogue Legacy and Shadowrun Returns. These don't allow limiting the framerate. I've noticed something odd is going on with at least Shadowrun Returns; fans spin faster when playing full screen (versus windowed with the same resolution). Oddly, the framerate is lower in fullscreen (25 vs 30 fps). Since I only have the Intel IGP in my MacBook, limiting CPU power using Volta might also affect GPU heat production.

Answer (score 0):

[Volta](http://volta.garymathews.com) can limit the power consumption of your processor. Setting the power limit to 25W for example, I can prevent the fans in my MacBook (Mid-2014 15" Pro with IGP) from spinning up when playing a game. Note that your System Integrity Protection settings need to be adjusted, however.

On a related note, [Turbo Boost Switcher](https://www.rugarciap.com/turbo-boost-switcher-for-os-x/) allows disabling Turbo Boost, limiting the clock frequency of the processor. In my experience, it doesn't always help to stop the CPU fan going to full blast.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you checked out [Can I manually limit the %CPU used by a process?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24998/can-i-manually-limit-the-cpu-used-by-a-process)