# Java 100 % CPU usage

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, java, activity-monitor

I am using IntelliJ IDEA compiler for Java programming on my MacBook Pro 2015 Retina (Yosemite). When I run some Java program in my activity monitor appears Java process and takes 100+% of CPU. The fans start to run loud since it's starting to heat up. Sometimes there are 5 and more same Java processes and couple of them are using 100%. Those processes are turned off when I quit IntelliJ or when I quit them manually.

Can somebody tell me why is this happening, or how to fix this if it is possible to fix?

Comment: How can you use above 100%?

Comment: @Rob It is using 100 % and more since each core is 100% I guess

Comment: Which Java program is it multi threaded. Basically it sounds like your computer is doing exactly what it should do. Why do you think there is an issue?

Comment: @Mark actually I didn't express myself correctly. When I run compiler and there is error in code (exception etc.) then it adds java process and it the processor temperature goes up to 70 degrees Celsius, until fans star to kick at max speed until I quit those process. that's why I think it is unusual.

Comment: What do you mean it adds java process? Surely IntelliJ and your program were already running (still seem normal though)

Comment: @Mark when I open activity monitor under CPU tab there are 4 or more Java processes that are running nearly 100 % each, maybe seems normal but does not look to me when I white some code and my MacBook is heating up and fans become really laud  like it's running some intense 3D game or rendering something

Answer (score 1):

You're running a program. It's using resources. If you want a program to run, it runs using any resources it needs as available. This is the intended behavior.

If you want to limit the resources available to your IDE, you can do that. Limiting the resources provided is pretty easy (provided you're willing to work with a little bit of third-party software.) You can use [`cputhrottle`](http://www.willnolan.com/cputhrottle/cputhrottle.html) to limit the usage at the system level (better explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24998/can-i-manually-limit-the-cpu-used-by-a-process).)